# swift: Specifying path to a public struct in a framework whenever framework name has a public entity with the name of the framework in it

Tags: swift, namespaces

suppose framework Foo has (sadly public) class Foo and a public struct Account

```
func fetchClient(guid: String) -> Foo.Account? {
```

yields a compiler error

> 'Account' is not a member type of class 'Foo.Foo'

What's the proper syntax to access (public) Account outside Foo?
(Lots of swearwords about class aliased to framework here)

Comment: Just `import Foo` and use the simple name `Account`? Is there another `Account` from another module?

Comment: exactly. Developers are so fond of namespaces that the art of prefixing entities is long forgotten :-D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such syntax yet. See also [this discussion](https://forums.swift.org/t/pitch-fully-qualified-name-syntax/28482) on Swift Forums which is discussing this exact issue.

As a workaround, you can import *just* the `Account` struct from `Foo`:

```
import struct Foo.Account
```

Now you won't see the class `Foo` and you can say `Foo.Account`.

If you also need the class `Foo`, or lots of other things in `Foo`, you can put a type alias for `Foo.Account` in a separate file, using the above technique.

```
// this is the entirety of the file:
import struct Foo.Account

typealias FooAccount = Account
```

Also, there is a module alias feature that allows you to rename `Foo` to something else, if you are using SPM. See the [Swift Evolution Proposal](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/main/proposals/0339-module-aliasing-for-disambiguation.md).